# how to load word documents in Qt with Aspose.words

Tags: qt, aspose.words

I'm using the Aspose.words library to load words documents into qt, but I'm getting the error **undefined reference to `Aspose::Words::DocumentBuilder::Writeln(System::String const&)'
**

I followed a tutorial on https://blog.aspose.com/en/words/generate-word-document-in-qt-applications-with-cpp-word-library/ and was hoping it would work, but unfortunately I had some errors

Comment: How are you trying to achieve so? What "some errors" have you got? Please provide a valid [mre], we cannot make assumptions about what you do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.